# How to sum factorials: $(n+1)! + n!$

Tags: factorial

How can the sum of factorials $(n+1)!+n!$ be simplified?

Comment: You might want to edit the title - as described, there are factorials, but there is not a binomial expansion (which typically refers to a situation like this: $(a+b)^n$).

Answer (score 6):

$$(n+1)! = (n+1) \times n!$$

and so $$(n+1)! + n! = (n+1) \times n! + n!$$

and $$(n+1) \times n! + n! = n! ((n+1) +1) = n!(n+2)$$

and hence $$\color{blue}{(n+1)! +n! = n!(n+2)}$$

Comment: Which is also equal to ${(n+2)!}\over{(n+1)}$, which might be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** $(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n!$. So...
$$
(n+1)! + n! = (n+1)\cdot n! + n! = ...
$$